# How can I create a Regex that only lets in comma separated numbers?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want my user to be able to add multiple numeric values separated by commas. For example,

**Allowed Strings**

```
1,2,3
.1,2.0,3.,
```

**Not Allowed**

```
1,,2..3
1,2,.,3,.
```

I have this so far:

```bash
/(\.?)(\d+)(,?)/g
```

As a bonus, I would also like to have the regex that I could give to the JS match method which will give me an array of the values entered by the user.

Comment: `match` method cannot give array of all comma separated numbers

Comment: @anubhava I think it will. At least thats what the regex documentation says.

Comment: ok, show me documentation that shows a way to return all repeated matches in separate capturing groups.

Comment: @anubhava Go to this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and find this code example: `const re = /\w+\s/g;
const str = 'fee fi fo fum';
const myArray = str.match(re);
console.log(myArray);

// ["fee ", "fi ", "fo "]
`

Comment: How is this code related to comma separated numbers shown in question?

Comment: @anubhava If I create a Regex that allows/validates only the values between two commas, the match function should give me an array of those values.

Comment: @anubhava Maybe this could be made more efficient but try this regex with the piece of code give above: `((\d*\.?\d+)|(\d+\.?\d*))`. It should give you an array of all comma separated values without the commas.

Comment: Now try that regex on `1,3#a12:1a` which is NOT a comma separated string containing numbers only

Comment: @anubhava I was not trying to have competition here. I know my regex does not cover every scenario. I am still learning. In fact I only started yesterday. The conversation was whether it is possible to get an array of matched strings/values from the match method or not. If I refine my regex, then I am pretty sure I could achieve that.

Comment: Not at all a competition. Read my comment again which still holds true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(((\d*\.?\d+)|(\d+\.?\d*))(,)|((\d*\.?\d+)|(\d+\.?\d*)))+$

^((\d+\.?\d*,?)|(\d+\.?\d+,?)|(\d*\.?\d+)(,?))+$
```

edit: thanks to @Brooke because my 1st answer had an error, now this one should work perfectly

edit2: the 2dn one is more understandable

Comment: Seems like this doesn't work with the second "Allowed String" in the question: `.1,2.0,3.,` returns "No match".

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I will probably end up spending quite some time figuring out how this works but it does work. Thanks!

Comment: @muezz you can use https://regexr.com/ it breaks down the regex for a better understanding

Answer (score 3):

You can use a function that will split the string by the comas and then check if `every` items are numbers (`!isNaN`) to decide to return the splitted string (an array) or something else.

```js
const allowed_1 = "1,2,3"
const allowed_2 = ".1,2.0,3.,"

const notAllowed_1 = "1,,2..3"
const notAllowed_2 = "1,2,.,3,."

const checkNumbers = (string) => {
  items = string.split(",")
  return items.every((item) => !isNaN(item)) ? items : "Not allowed"
}

console.log(checkNumbers(allowed_1))
console.log(checkNumbers(allowed_2))

console.log(checkNumbers(notAllowed_1))
console.log(checkNumbers(notAllowed_2))
```

Comment: I know this works just fine but I want to use Regex to handle this. Its just a personal choice at this point. Your method works too.